# Android сохранение файла

Tags: java, android

У меня тут возникала проблема вообщем я создаю файл программно в android и хочу сохранить его, но не в папке приложения а где-нибуть в другом месте, но и не на флешке, но не знаю как это сделать?
На данный момент файл сохраняю таким образом:

```
String filename = "backup_file.txt";

String stringXOR = StringXOR.encode(backup_bd, "01982734650");
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(filename, MODE_PRIVATE);
    OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);
    outputWriter.write(stringXOR);
    outputWriter.close();

    // TODO: Создаем всплывающее окно c результатом выполнения записи в файл
    showMessage(getString(R.string.file_save) + " android/data/ru.myapp/files/" + filename);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    showMessage(e.getMessage());
}
prgDialog.hide();
```

Comment: Поменяйте путь android/data/ru.myapp/files/ на "куда нужно"

Comment: _"но не в папке приложения а где-нибуть в другом месте, но и не на флешке"_ - а где тогда? В космосе? Непонятно что Вы хотите...

Comment: @РусланЯгупов Если вы не заметили то то, что вы предлогаете редактировать это вывод сообщения

Comment: @woesss ну например просто сохранить файл в корне телефона т.е. просто когда заходишь в файловый менеджер видишь там валяющийся файл с названием backup_file.txt, потому что на данный момент он сохраняется в папке с root правами, а мне это не надо

Comment: В корень файловой системы без рута писать нельзя. _"когда заходишь в файловый менеджер"_ - большинство из них отображают корень "внешней памяти", в роли которой может быть или специально выделенная часть встроенной памяти, или съёмный накопитель(ака флешка, которую Вы не хотите). Если в аппарате есть и съёмный накопитель и встроенный, то найти где кто вопрос отдельный и довольно не простой.

Answer (score 0):

Файл можно сохранить так:

```
File file = new File(filepath);
try (OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))) {
    os.write(source.readByteArray());
}
```